# Unable to Change backgroundImage using Material UI V5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

I am working on a chat application using material UI and I'm facing an issue with changing the background image of the chat screen. I've tried setting the background image using `backgroundImage: url(${BackgroundImage})`, but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried using the selector `'& .MuiBox-root' with backgroundImage`, but it shows multiple images when there is chat response and shows nothing when there is no response.

I have attempted to troubleshoot the problem but have been unsuccessful so far. Could you please assist me in finding a solution to this issue?

here is my code:

```
return (

    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        '& .MuiBox-root': {
          backgroundImage:`url(${BackgroundImage})`,
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        },
       
      }}
    >
      <Box
        ref={chatBoxRef}
        sx={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          overflowY: 'auto',
          width: '100%',
          maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 150px)',
          
        }}

      >
        {chatHistory.map((message, index) => (
          <Box
            key={index}
            sx={{
              padding: '0.5rem 30rem',
              width: '100%',
              wordWrap: 'break-word',
              overflowWrap: 'break-word',
              maxWidth: '100%',
              '@media (max-width: 1700px)': {
                padding: '0.5rem 15rem',
              },
              '@media (max-width: 1024px)': {
                padding: '0.5rem 5rem',
              },
              '@media (max-width: 600px)': {
                padding: '0.5rem 2rem',
              },
            }}
          >
           {message.message}
            
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
      <Box
        sx={{
          position: 'fixed',
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: '0.5rem 30rem',
          borderTop: '1px solid #ccc',
          '@media (max-width: 1700px)': {
            padding: '0.5rem 15rem',
          },
          '@media (max-width: 1024px)': {
            padding: '0.5rem 5rem',
          },
          '@media (max-width: 600px)': {
            padding: '0.5rem 2rem',
          },
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          label="Enter your question"
          multiline
          sx={{
            marginTop: 'auto',
            boxShadow: '0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
          }}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <SendIcon
                onClick={handleQuestion}
                sx={{ color: '#9900ff', cursor: 'pointer' }}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />

        <DeleteIcon
          onClick={handleChat}
          variant="outlined"
          size="small"
          sx={{ color: '#9900ff', cursor: 'pointer', fontSize: '2.5rem' }}
        />
      </Box>
    </Box>

  );
```

Image when I use elector `'& .MuiBox-root' with backgroundImage`[image: Image using selector]